# macOS fails to load on Mid-2010 MacBook Pro with SSD upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, ssd, upgrade

I have a mid-2010 13" MacBook Pro that I'm trying to upgrade by swapping the HDD with a 1TB SSD, and it's giving me trouble.

I installed the latest version of High Sierra, the last OS officially supported on that model, on the clean SSD, and I've encountered the following issue:

1. When the system is cold booted, it fails to load the OS and ends up displaying the prohibitory sign. When started in verbose mode, it displays the following message: `Still waiting for root device`.
2. From the state above, if I force the system to shut down by pressing the power button, and then start it back up, the OS loads successfully, I can log in, and everything works fine.
3. From there, the system can go to sleep and resume without issue, but if I reboot it, it goes back to (1).

Before the drive swap, the system had the following upgrades, which have been all in place for months to years without issue:

- Replaced the original 256GB HDD with a 512GB one.
- Upgraded the RAM from the initial 4GB configuration to 16GB.
- Replaced the original battery, which had swollen up, with an aftermarket one.

Troubleshooting so far:

- Re-formatted the drive and re-installed the OS. Same problem.
- Tried starting up to the startup manager (Option key) and made sure that there were no other volumes interfering with the startup process. As expected from a vanilla install, the startup manager shows no bootable volumes other than the SSD.
- Moved the SSD to a different computer (mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro), and I could not reproduce the issue.

I've researched the error message above, but I couldn't find any case similar to mine, where the OS would not load on cold start, but would then work on reboot.

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS was on the HD prior to this change? I get the feeling you missed a firmware update somewhere along the line. The only way to confirm that [from my *very* limited knowledge] would be to first set it up with El Capitan, then upgrade to High Sierra. Not posting as an answer because I'm sure even if I'm right, someone smarter than me could think of a better way;)

Comment: How did you install the OS onto the clean drive, exactly? Booting to an external disk, and using the Installer app, or an installer-disk made using `createinstallmedia`?

Comment: I think Tetsujin has a good point. Check: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518

Comment: Have you try to put the ssd in a USB enclosure and boot on this external ssd? If that's right, maybe you have to change the internal disk cable.